# Moving ASP.NET web application to a 'cloud' - has anybody actually done this?

Tags: hosting, asp.net, cloud-computing

Has anybody out there actually moved an ASP.NET application from a traditional hosting environment/situation - i.e. where you own the kit, or use Rackspace - to using a cloud service/provider?

Does this even exist? Is that what Azure is all about? Do you have any lessons/advice to share?

Answer (score 2):

We were part of the community test of the Azure Cloud.  I can tell you that the ASP hosting of the Azure cloud is very promising.  We were able to deploy an ASP app in the cloud with minimal changes to our development strategy.

1. The Azure Service SDK only runs in Vista
2. We did not test to port an existent application with the Azure SDK, but the actual built from scratch was not difficult.

You can read a few more details in the following [link](http://blog.readytocloud.com/search/label/Azure). I hope this information helps you.  The short answer to your question is yes, is possible and many people have already done it.  It exists, either in Azure or in EC2 (at a different level).

Regards, Geo

Answer (score 2):

[Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/windows/) has been hosting ASP.NET apps for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com). AppHarbor makes moving your application to the cloud incredibly easy, and scaling your apps is also as simple as clicking a button. We feel that AppHarbor is Azure Done Right.

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of AppHarbor)

Answer (score -1):

Read the http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/creating-a-database-unit-test-using-visual-studio-2010/ post to move your asp.net application

Comment: It would be nice if you gave a little more context than just the link.